# How do I make sure to initialize only one Instance but from another class?

Tags: java, constructor, singleton

I recently read about the singleton principle but I dont quite get how I can initialize this single instance of a class form another class if the constructor is `private`. And how do I set parameters from another class if the constructor is supposed to be `private`?

```
public class Player {

    String name;
    Position p;
    Inventory i;

    private Player(String name, Position p, Inventory i){

    }

    static {
        instance = 
    }

    public static Player getPlayer(){
        return instance;
    }

}
```

Comment: then you haven't understood singleton correctly. In singleton there's no `setter` method. Member variables are set at the time of instance creation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a `private static Player` variable, and in your `getPlayer()` method or in the static block create the object and assign to the above variable if it's null.

```
public static Player getPlayer(){
    if(player == null){
        player = new Player("name", p, i);
    }
    return player;
}
```

this way you create only a single instance.

---

Simple rules,

1. The constructor of the class should be `private`.
2. Keep the object in a `private static` variable.
3. Create a getter for the singleton object (no setters).
4. You can also add `synchronized` to the getter to make it thread safe (optional).

Comment: This code is not thread-safe. Multiple threads might see the `player` is `null` and initialize a different `Player` instances. More over, the default constructor is not declared, you cannot use it

Comment: Am I allowed to create setters for the object attributes or is this also against the singleton principle?

Comment: @FabianZbinden That's ok, as long as the only static object is your Player object. Which means all the other variables are inside that object.

Answer (score 1):

In another class you call: `Player.getPlayer()`

It always return the only one static instance of your class. The constructor is private so other class cannot initialize your class via constructor.

The only way to obtain your `Player` instance is via the static method `Player.getPlayer()` hence it's singleton.

```
public class Player {

    String name;
    Position p;
    Inventory i;


    private static final Player instance = new Player(.....your argument....);

    private Player(String name, Position p, Inventory i){

    } 

    public static Player getPlayer(){
        return instance;
    }

}
```

Comment: and I'll need `getters` to access members

Answer (score 1):

Basically, with this approach you hide the constructor (`private`) and exposes a static method for getting the `instance`. In the method you check if the `instance` if `null`, if so, you initialise it with the provided arguments.

Finally you return the `instance`.

**Notice** here if you call the `getPlayer` method more than once, the instance will be created (and will be the same in further calls of method `getPlayer`) with the arguments provided the first time the static method was called.

```
public class Player {

    String name;
    Position p;
    Inventory i;

    private static Player instance;

    private Player(String name, Position p, Inventory i){
        // ...
    }

    public static Player getPlayer(String name, Position p, Inventory i){
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new Player(name, p, i);
        }
        return instance;
    }

}
```

Additionally, if you want to use the singleton pattern properly, you should not set the attributes (no setters methods) once the instance is created.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare a private static final `INSTANCE` field as

```
private static final INSTANCE = new Person(name, p, i);
```